# Server reporting incorrect mime type for css files

Tags: css, apache-2.2, mime

We have a VPS server that we host our websites on. I have written a CMS using CodeIgniter. On one of the interfaces, I am attempting to upload a css file to the system. This worked correctly when we had it hosted on shared hosting. Since we've moved it to the VPS, I am getting an "incorrect filetype" error.

It all comes down to the fact that the server is reporting a mime type of **text/x-c** for the css file rather than **text/css**.

I logged in via shell and ran the following command on an existing *valid* css file (to make sure it wasn't an issue with either CodeIgniter or with php).

```
file --brief --mime 'filename.css' 2>&1
```

The server gave me the following in response to my command:

```
text/x-c; charset=us-ascii
```

My question ... is there some sort of server setting that I need to tweak to get the server to correctly identify the css file as **text/css**?

Do I just have to add a mime type for the css files to the server? I found the mime types file (**etc/mime.types**), and it just hase video types and a couple other that I have no idea what they are. There is nothing in there for css or images or html files. Unless I'm looking in the wrong spot.

I'm not a server person, so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Some server specs:

- Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
- php 5.3.13
- Server API = CGI/FastCGI
- the **fileinfo** php extension appears to be disabled

Comment: I voted to move this to serverfault since it's not a programming question.

Comment: You might want to file a bug against the `file` package.  For text files, they are pretty much tied to weak heuristics (the `magic` library only examines content, not file name extensions etc) but it should not be too hard for them to prevent obvious false positives.  They'll probably want a copy of the file which caused the false positive if you can provide it.

Comment: Sad to say, but I gave up. Hosting support told me to contact CodeIgniter support (basically passing the buck). I just modified my mimes config file so that CodeIgniter would think a mime type of "text/x-c" was a css file. Luckily the only place css files can be uploaded is an interface only I have access to. It's a bandaid, but I don't know enough about servers to try to figure out the issue.

Comment: @Becky - if you happen to run across a solution please post back.  I have a similar problem and other than blowing out the entire apache installation and resintalling, I don't know what else to do.  css is listed in /etc/mime.types, but is still being served as text/html.  http://serverfault.com/questions/436481/incorrect-mime-type-pulling-my-hair-out#comment469888_436481

Answer (score 3):

Modify the mime.types file by adding the following:

```
text/css     css
```

Below are the contents of the mime.types file I use on one of my Apache servers. I am fairly certain that it covers pretty much all types of files that your (or any) server may serve up to users. I would suggest making the change to your VPS's mime.types file to include everything below, especially if there is nothing there relating to css, images, or html files.

```
# MIME type         Extension
application/EDI-Consent
application/EDI-X12
application/EDIFACT
application/activemessage
application/andrew-inset    ez
application/applefile
application/atomicmail
application/batch-SMTP
application/beep+xml
application/cals-1840
application/commonground
application/cybercash
application/dca-rft
application/dec-dx
application/dvcs
application/eshop
application/http
application/hyperstudio
application/iges
application/index
application/index.cmd
application/index.obj
application/index.response
application/index.vnd
application/iotp
application/ipp
application/isup
application/font-tdpfr
application/mac-binhex40    hqx
application/mac-compactpro  cpt
application/macwriteii
application/marc
application/mathematica
application/mathematica-old
application/msword      doc
application/news-message-id
application/news-transmission
application/ocsp-request
application/ocsp-response
application/octet-stream    bin dms lha lzh exe class so dll
application/oda         oda
application/parityfec
application/pdf         pdf
application/pgp-encrypted
application/pgp-keys
application/pgp-signature
application/pkcs10
application/pkcs7-mime
application/pkcs7-signature
application/pkix-cert
application/pkix-crl
application/pkixcmp
application/postscript      ai eps ps
application/prs.alvestrand.titrax-sheet
application/prs.cww
application/prs.nprend
application/qsig
application/remote-printing
application/riscos
application/rtf
application/sdp
application/set-payment
application/set-payment-initiation
application/set-registration
application/set-registration-initiation
application/sgml
application/sgml-open-catalog
application/sieve
application/slate
application/smil        smi smil
application/timestamp-query
application/timestamp-reply
application/vemmi
application/vnd.3M.Post-it-Notes
application/vnd.FloGraphIt
application/vnd.accpac.simply.aso
application/vnd.accpac.simply.imp
application/vnd.acucobol
application/vnd.aether.imp
application/vnd.anser-web-certificate-issue-initiation
application/vnd.anser-web-funds-transfer-initiation
application/vnd.audiograph
application/vnd.businessobjects
application/vnd.bmi
application/vnd.canon-cpdl
application/vnd.canon-lips
application/vnd.claymore
application/vnd.commerce-battelle
application/vnd.commonspace
application/vnd.comsocaller
application/vnd.contact.cmsg
application/vnd.cosmocaller
application/vnd.cups-postscript
application/vnd.cups-raster
application/vnd.cups-raw
application/vnd.ctc-posml
application/vnd.cybank
application/vnd.dna
application/vnd.dpgraph
application/vnd.dxr
application/vnd.ecdis-update
application/vnd.ecowin.chart
application/vnd.ecowin.filerequest
application/vnd.ecowin.fileupdate
application/vnd.ecowin.series
application/vnd.ecowin.seriesrequest
application/vnd.ecowin.seriesupdate
application/vnd.enliven
application/vnd.epson.esf
application/vnd.epson.msf
application/vnd.epson.quickanime
application/vnd.epson.salt
application/vnd.epson.ssf
application/vnd.ericsson.quickcall
application/vnd.eudora.data
application/vnd.fdf
application/vnd.ffsns
application/vnd.framemaker
application/vnd.fsc.weblaunch
application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys
application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys2
application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys3
application/vnd.fujitsu.oasysgp
application/vnd.fujitsu.oasysprs
application/vnd.fujixerox.ddd
application/vnd.fujixerox.docuworks
application/vnd.fujixerox.docuworks.binder
application/vnd.fut-misnet
application/vnd.grafeq
application/vnd.groove-account
application/vnd.groove-identity-message
application/vnd.groove-injector
application/vnd.groove-tool-message
application/vnd.groove-tool-template
application/vnd.groove-vcard
application/vnd.hhe.lesson-player
application/vnd.hp-HPGL
application/vnd.hp-PCL
application/vnd.hp-PCLXL
application/vnd.hp-hpid
application/vnd.hp-hps
application/vnd.httphone
application/vnd.hzn-3d-crossword
application/vnd.ibm.afplinedata
application/vnd.ibm.MiniPay
application/vnd.ibm.modcap
application/vnd.informix-visionary
application/vnd.intercon.formnet
application/vnd.intertrust.digibox
application/vnd.intertrust.nncp
application/vnd.intu.qbo
application/vnd.intu.qfx
application/vnd.irepository.package+xml
application/vnd.is-xpr
application/vnd.japannet-directory-service
application/vnd.japannet-jpnstore-wakeup
application/vnd.japannet-payment-wakeup
application/vnd.japannet-registration
application/vnd.japannet-registration-wakeup
application/vnd.japannet-setstore-wakeup
application/vnd.japannet-verification
application/vnd.japannet-verification-wakeup
application/vnd.koan
application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3
application/vnd.lotus-approach
application/vnd.lotus-freelance
application/vnd.lotus-notes
application/vnd.lotus-organizer
application/vnd.lotus-screencam
application/vnd.lotus-wordpro
application/vnd.mcd
application/vnd.mediastation.cdkey
application/vnd.meridian-slingshot
application/vnd.mif     mif
application/vnd.minisoft-hp3000-save
application/vnd.mitsubishi.misty-guard.trustweb
application/vnd.mobius.daf
application/vnd.mobius.dis
application/vnd.mobius.msl
application/vnd.mobius.plc
application/vnd.mobius.txf
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite.adsi
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite.fis
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite.gotap
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite.kmr
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite.ttc
application/vnd.motorola.flexsuite.wem
application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml
application/vnd.ms-artgalry
application/vnd.ms-asf
application/vnd.ms-excel    xls
application/vnd.ms-lrm
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint   ppt
application/vnd.ms-project
application/vnd.ms-tnef
application/vnd.ms-works
application/vnd.mseq
application/vnd.msign
application/vnd.music-niff
application/vnd.musician
application/vnd.netfpx
application/vnd.noblenet-directory
application/vnd.noblenet-sealer
application/vnd.noblenet-web
application/vnd.novadigm.EDM
application/vnd.novadigm.EDX
application/vnd.novadigm.EXT
application/vnd.osa.netdeploy
application/vnd.palm
application/vnd.pg.format
application/vnd.pg.osasli
application/vnd.powerbuilder6
application/vnd.powerbuilder6-s
application/vnd.powerbuilder7
application/vnd.powerbuilder7-s
application/vnd.powerbuilder75
application/vnd.powerbuilder75-s
application/vnd.previewsystems.box
application/vnd.publishare-delta-tree
application/vnd.pvi.ptid1
application/vnd.pwg-xhtml-print+xml
application/vnd.rapid
application/vnd.s3sms
application/vnd.seemail
application/vnd.shana.informed.formdata
application/vnd.shana.informed.formtemplate
application/vnd.shana.informed.interchange
application/vnd.shana.informed.package
application/vnd.sss-cod
application/vnd.sss-dtf
application/vnd.sss-ntf
application/vnd.street-stream
application/vnd.svd
application/vnd.swiftview-ics
application/vnd.triscape.mxs
application/vnd.trueapp
application/vnd.truedoc
application/vnd.tve-trigger
application/vnd.ufdl
application/vnd.uplanet.alert
application/vnd.uplanet.alert-wbxml
application/vnd.uplanet.bearer-choice-wbxml
application/vnd.uplanet.bearer-choice
application/vnd.uplanet.cacheop
application/vnd.uplanet.cacheop-wbxml
application/vnd.uplanet.channel
application/vnd.uplanet.channel-wbxml
application/vnd.uplanet.list
application/vnd.uplanet.list-wbxml
application/vnd.uplanet.listcmd
application/vnd.uplanet.listcmd-wbxml
application/vnd.uplanet.signal
application/vnd.vcx
application/vnd.vectorworks
application/vnd.vidsoft.vidconference
application/vnd.visio
application/vnd.vividence.scriptfile
application/vnd.wap.sic
application/vnd.wap.slc
application/vnd.wap.wbxml   wbxml
application/vnd.wap.wmlc    wmlc
application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc  wmlsc
application/vnd.webturbo
application/vnd.wrq-hp3000-labelled
application/vnd.wt.stf
application/vnd.xara
application/vnd.xfdl
application/vnd.yellowriver-custom-menu
application/whoispp-query
application/whoispp-response
application/wita
application/wordperfect5.1
application/x-bcpio     bcpio
application/x-cdlink        vcd
application/x-chess-pgn     pgn
application/x-compress
application/x-cpio      cpio
application/x-csh       csh
application/x-director      dcr dir dxr
application/x-dvi       dvi
application/x-futuresplash  spl
application/x-gtar      gtar
application/x-gzip
application/x-hdf       hdf
application/x-javascript    js
application/x-koan      skp skd skt skm
application/x-latex     latex
application/x-netcdf        nc cdf
application/x-sh        sh
application/x-shar      shar
application/x-shockwave-flash   swf
application/x-stuffit       sit
application/x-sv4cpio       sv4cpio
application/x-sv4crc        sv4crc
application/x-tar       tar
application/x-tcl       tcl
application/x-tex       tex
application/x-texinfo       texinfo texi
application/x-troff     t tr roff
application/x-troff-man     man
application/x-troff-me      me
application/x-troff-ms      ms
application/x-ustar     ustar
application/x-wais-source   src
application/x400-bp
application/xhtml+xml       xhtml xht
application/xml
application/xml-dtd
application/xml-external-parsed-entity
application/zip         zip
audio/32kadpcm
audio/basic         au snd
audio/g.722.1
audio/l16
audio/midi          mid midi kar
audio/mp4a-latm
audio/mpa-robust
audio/mpeg          mpga mp2 mp3
audio/parityfec
audio/prs.sid
audio/telephone-event
audio/tone
audio/vnd.cisco.nse
audio/vnd.cns.anp1
audio/vnd.cns.inf1
audio/vnd.digital-winds
audio/vnd.everad.plj
audio/vnd.lucent.voice
audio/vnd.nortel.vbk
audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp4800
audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp7470
audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp9600
audio/vnd.octel.sbc
audio/vnd.qcelp
audio/vnd.rhetorex.32kadpcm
audio/vnd.vmx.cvsd
audio/x-aiff            aif aiff aifc
audio/x-mpegurl         m3u
audio/x-pn-realaudio        ram rm
audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin rpm
audio/x-realaudio       ra
audio/x-wav         wav
chemical/x-pdb          pdb
chemical/x-xyz          xyz
image/bmp           bmp
image/cgm
image/g3fax
image/gif           gif
image/ief           ief
image/jpeg          jpeg jpg jpe
image/naplps
image/png           png
image/prs.btif
image/prs.pti
image/tiff          tiff tif
image/vnd.cns.inf2
image/vnd.djvu          djvu djv
image/vnd.dwg
image/vnd.dxf
image/vnd.fastbidsheet
image/vnd.fpx
image/vnd.fst
image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-mmr
image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-rlc
image/vnd.mix
image/vnd.net-fpx
image/vnd.svf
image/vnd.wap.wbmp      wbmp
image/vnd.xiff
image/x-cmu-raster      ras
image/x-portable-anymap     pnm
image/x-portable-bitmap     pbm
image/x-portable-graymap    pgm
image/x-portable-pixmap     ppm
image/x-rgb         rgb
image/x-xbitmap         xbm
image/x-xpixmap         xpm
image/x-xwindowdump     xwd
message/delivery-status
message/disposition-notification
message/external-body
message/http
message/news
message/partial
message/rfc822
message/s-http
model/iges          igs iges
model/mesh          msh mesh silo
model/vnd.dwf
model/vnd.flatland.3dml
model/vnd.gdl
model/vnd.gs-gdl
model/vnd.gtw
model/vnd.mts
model/vnd.vtu
model/vrml          wrl vrml
multipart/alternative
multipart/appledouble
multipart/byteranges
multipart/digest
multipart/encrypted
multipart/form-data
multipart/header-set
multipart/mixed
multipart/parallel
multipart/related
multipart/report
multipart/signed
multipart/voice-message
text/cache-manifest     appcache manifest
text/calendar
text/css            css
text/directory
text/enriched
text/html           html htm
text/parityfec
text/plain          asc txt
text/prs.lines.tag
text/rfc822-headers
text/richtext           rtx
text/rtf            rtf
text/sgml           sgml sgm
text/tab-separated-values   tsv
text/t140
text/uri-list
text/vnd.DMClientScript
text/vnd.IPTC.NITF
text/vnd.IPTC.NewsML
text/vnd.abc
text/vnd.curl
text/vnd.flatland.3dml
text/vnd.fly
text/vnd.fmi.flexstor
text/vnd.in3d.3dml
text/vnd.in3d.spot
text/vnd.latex-z
text/vnd.motorola.reflex
text/vnd.ms-mediapackage
text/vnd.wap.si
text/vnd.wap.sl
text/vnd.wap.wml        wml
text/vnd.wap.wmlscript      wmls
text/x-setext           etx
text/xml            xml xsl
text/xml-external-parsed-entity
video/mp4v-es
video/mpeg          mpeg mpg mpe
video/parityfec
video/pointer
video/quicktime         qt mov
video/vnd.fvt
video/vnd.motorola.video
video/vnd.motorola.videop
video/vnd.mpegurl       mxu
video/vnd.mts
video/vnd.nokia.interleaved-multimedia
video/vnd.vivo
video/x-msvideo         avi
video/x-sgi-movie       movie
x-conference/x-cooltalk     ice
```

Comment: Apparently the "text/css" value is already in the mime.types file. Which is why I am confused that the server is returning "text/x-c". The host support is telling me to contact CodeIgniter support to fix the issue. I'm not sure how it's a CI issue when the server, separate from CI, is giving me the wrong value. I'm at a loss ...

Comment: Yeah, I can't see how it would be a CI issue either, especially if the application was working fine on a when on another Apache server (even if it was a shared server).

Comment: It's not a CI issue. Not if shell is returning the wrong type. Maybe it's how you transferred the files? If you used ftp check your transfer settings.

Comment: If you can ssh into the server and get to the directory that the CSS file is in, do a `ls -al` and see what the full filename and extension of the file is. As thelastshadow suggested, maybe the file got messed up during transfer?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding

```
AddType text/css css
```

to your .htaccess file?

Comment: I did try that. It didn't help. I'm not sure if the directive is being ignored or not. I think I would need to modify the **httpd.conf** file, but I'm not comfortable doing that. I submitted a ticket to the host.

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: I believe it's Apache 2.2.22 (Unix) with php 5.3.13.