# Apache doesn't send me an MP3 header even when I use a direct address to the file

Tags: apache-2.2, php, http-headers, mp3

Apache doesn't send me an [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) header even when using a direct address to the file. It means I can play it with [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) audio players on my web pages, but when I tried to download from the direct address on my server I got:

> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset

Or it sometimes gives me a file with a `.mp3` file extension that just has a file size of 13 bytes. When I open that file in [gedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit)/[Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) there is just:

```
<html></html>
```

I don't have any problem with [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) files and images, but the MP3 files are never send to the browser for download or play.

I added the following code to `httpd.conf`, but there is not any difference!

```
AddType audio/mpeg   .mp3
```

Comment: Did you restart the Apache service after that modification?

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser? (trying to eliminate that the problem is on the client side).

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your mime.types file not your httpd.conf file. Add (or modify) the following line to your mime.types file and restart Apache.

```
audio/mpeg          mpga mp2 mp3
```

See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/434220/server-reporting-incorrect-mime-type-for-css-files/434303#434303) post about for an example mime.types file that should cover all of your application's needs.

Comment: `audio/mpeg  mpga mp2 mp2a mp3 m2a m3a` should already be in any recent builds of Apache.

Comment: Should be, but who knows what version/build the OP is on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
```

And then restart apache.